# D missing from terminal keybinds - have to add it on every login

Tags: command-line, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have been running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 on my Thinkpad T420 for a couple months now, and so far it has been great. However, A couple days ago my "d"(lowercase only) key stopped working in any terminal application. Whenever I press "d", I just get the GNOME beep sound, and d won't be input. I can press Ctrl + V then "d", and that seems to work.

When I noticed this, I hit up some IRCs and was told to do this command:

```
bind -p | less
```

I did so, and the file was fine, for the most part. I found the listing for all the alphabet keys, and d was missing. it says this:

```
"a": self-insert
"b": self-insert
"c": self-insert
"e": self-insert
```

I proceeded to add d using

```
bind d:self-insert
```

and d started working in terminal again, however, whenever I close the terminal, it seems to forget this setting. I hate having to enter this command EVERY time I log in, and I would love to fix it. Any ideas?

EDIT: The contents of my /etc/inputrc file: http://pastebin.com/vnGy9n1i

Comment: Which package contains `bind` o_O

Comment: @A.B., `bind` is a `bash` internal command. @Johan --- really puzzling. Have you installed something before the problem started? Otherwise you can try search all startup files for a "bind" command.

Comment: Ah, bash. I'm using zsh =)

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `cat ~/.inputrc` and `cat /etc/inputrc`

Comment: Just did. I don't have any file called ~/.inputrc however.

Comment: Until you find a real answer to your problem, you can add the bind command to $HOME/.bashrc and it will be run whenever you open a shell (at least if you're using bash). It's likely that there are equivalent options for other shells.

Comment: @Joe using `~/.profile` will work for various shells (including bash) and has the benefit of not running a command each time you open a terminal.

Comment: @terdon - Yes, that's usually better - unless something has reset/changed it since the login shell started.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably set `d` as a keyboard shortcut for something. The likeliest culprit will be a shortcut set up in `Preferences => Shortcuts` of `gnome-terminal`. Make sure you haven't set <kbd>D</kbd> to something there.

If you are using `xbindkeys`, have a look at `~/.xbindkyesrc` and remove the offending entry. Alternatively, check your desktop envoronment's keyboard shortcut settings and see if you've set anything up there (but I doubt that would cause the issue you describe).

Another possibility is that you have a `bind` command in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` (or any other shell setup file) files that disables the `d`. To test for that, try

```
grep --color -H bind ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login \
                     ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile \
                     /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null
```

If there is such a command, that should show it.

Finally, as a temporary workaround, just add this line to your `~/.profile` (and not to `~/.bashrc`):

```
bind d:self-insert
```